# getting the period of dates for each employee

Tags: mysql, sql

I have one table "EMPLOYEEMASTER" contains 'emp id' as 1,2,3,4.....

The date is between 21 of one month to 20 of the next month.....

```
EMPLOYEEMASTER
--------------
emp id       name     
------       ----
1            anil
2            babu
3            anitha
```

i want the sql statement for getting like

```
emp id         date
------         ----
1              21/03/2011
1              22/03/2011
1              23/03/2011
1              24/03/2011
.              .
.              .

.              .
.
1              30/03/2011
1              01/04/2011
.              .
.              .
1              19/04/2011
1              20/04/2011
2              21/04/2011
2              22/04/2011
.....
```

plz help me?...

Comment: Can you do a describe on the table and select the first few rows with data as an example?  Not really sure what you want in your output.

Comment: Please describe the complete database structure. from where the date came here as per your described data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm going to assume that there is also a table that includes the employee id and their begin/end dates too...

```
SELECT a.Id, b.BeginDate, b.EndDate
FROM EMPLOYEEMASTER As a
LEFT JOIN EMPLOYEEDATES As b --whatever table the id and dates are in
ON a.Id = b.Id
```

"Generic questions get generic answers"